# "Semantic error at paths./MyType.get.responses.200.schema.$ref $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs"

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, swagger-2.0

I installed **swashbuckle.OData** and **swashbuckle** with nuget in my **OData API**. When I run the application then in browser I put "**swagger**" after "**localhost:53000**" in address bar (***localhost:53000/swagger***). And it gives me its swagger document like below picture:

[image]

And I paste the received address(localhost:53000/swagger/docs/v1) in address bar of another tab in my browser and then it gives me some data in json format and I copy and paste whole of that data to website of "[editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io)" and then I encounter errors in "editor.swagger.io". The error is ==>> (Semantic error at paths ./BankBranches.get.responses.200.schema.$ref $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs).

This error is because of "[" and "]" in part of responses in swagger editor ==>> $ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponse[List[BankBranch]]'.

```
/BankBranches:
    get:
      tags:
        - BankBranches
      summary: Returns the EntitySet BankBranches
      operationId: BankBranches_GetBankBranches
      consumes: []
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: $expand
          in: query
          description: Expands related entities inline.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: $filter
          in: query
          description: 'Filters the results, based on a Boolean condition.'
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: $select
          in: query
          description: Selects which properties to include in the response.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: $orderby
          in: query
          description: Sorts the results.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: $top
          in: query
          description: Returns only the first n results.
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
        - name: $skip
          in: query
          description: Skips the first n results.
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
        - name: $count
          in: query
          description: Includes a count of the matching results in the response.
          required: false
          type: boolean
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponse[List[BankBranch]]'
      deprecated: false
```

I know that I must remove "[" and "]". I mean if I change the ($ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponse[List[BankBranch]]') into ($ref: '#/definitions/ODataResponseListBankBranch') then the problem will be solved. I do not know how to make my **OData API** not to create this error????